# Angular: Default currency code for 'en-GB' is USD

Tags: angular, locale

I have this in my `app.module.ts`:

```
const initLocaleProvider = {
  provide: LOCALE_ID,
  useFactory: (confService: ConfigService) => confService.config.uiCulture,
  deps: [ConfigService]
};

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    initLocaleProvider
  ]
})
```

With this code the `LOCALE_ID` is successfully set to `en-GB`.

Now, I tried to format decimal numbers with `number` pipe and this works correctly. But when I try to translate number to currency through `pipe.translate` or through `{{ number | currency }}`, in both cases I get the value with `$` sign, not the `£` one.

I checked the currency pipe in component and it's `_defaultCurrencyCode` is set to `USD` for some reason.

So, why the `LOCALE_ID` does not set the `_defaultCurrencyCode` correctly?

Comment: What about **en-UK**? (Not acquainted with Great Brittain)

Comment: @JoopEggen Nope, ```en-UK``` has ```_defaultCurrencyCode``` set to ```USD``` too.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding this additional provider:

```
// app.module.ts
const initCurrencyCodeProvider = {
  provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE,
  useFactory: (confService: ConfigService) => {
    return getLocaleCurrencyCode(confService.config.uiCulture);
  },
  deps: [ConfigService]
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    initCurrencyCodeProvider,
  ]
})
```

The `LOCALE_ID` token influences only form of the currency number (e.g. on which side the symbol is), but not the currency symbol itself.

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? [This says](https://angular.io/api/core/DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE) that *In v10 the default currency code will be taken from the current locale*